# Usng StringJoiner in complex HashMaps

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist, collections, hashmap

I have a list of Maps as below:

```
List<Map<String,Object>> someObjectsList = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();
```

I am storing the following data in each HashMap

```
key             value
2017-07-21      2017-07-21-07.33.28.429340
2017-07-24      2017-07-24-01.23.33.591340
2017-07-24      2017-07-24-01.23.33.492340
2017-07-21      2017-07-21-07.33.28.429540
```

I want to iterate through the list of `HashMap`s and check if the key matches with the first 10 characters of any of the `HashMap` value, then I want to store those keys and values in the following format. i.e. by using the telemeter 'comma'. The ultimate aim is to group the unique keys of the HashMaps and their relative values (if the key matches with the first 10 characters of any of the `HashMap` value) in a new HashMap.

```
key          value
2017-07-21  2017-07-21-07.33.28.429340,2017-07-21-07.33.28.429540
2017-07-24  2017-07-24-01.23.33.591340,2017-07-24-01.23.33.492340
```

I am trying with following java code using `StringJoiner`, but not getting the results as expected. Any clue on how to frame the logic here?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.StringJoiner;

public class SampleOne {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<Map<String, Object>> someObjectsList = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

        Map<String, Object> mapOne = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        mapOne.put("2017-07-21", "2017-07-21-07.33.28.429340");

        Map<String, Object> mapTwo = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        mapTwo.put("2017-07-24", "2017-07-24-01.23.33.591340");

        Map<String, Object> mapThree = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        mapThree.put("2017-07-24", "2017-07-24-01.23.33.492340");

        Map<String, Object> mapFour = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        mapFour.put("2017-07-21", "2017-07-21-07.33.28.429540");

        someObjectsList.add(mapOne);
        someObjectsList.add(mapTwo);
        someObjectsList.add(mapThree);
        someObjectsList.add(mapFour);

        for (Map map : someObjectsList) {
            StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(",");
            for (Object key : map.keySet()) {
                String value = ((String) map.get(key));
                String date = value.substring(0, Math.min(value.length(), 10));
                //System.out.println(str);
                //System.out.println(value);

                if(key.equals(date)) {
                    sj.add(value);
                    System.out.println(sj.toString());
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

output:

```
2017-07-21-07.33.28.429340
2017-07-24-01.23.33.591340
2017-07-24-01.23.33.492340
2017-07-21-07.33.28.429540
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of the [.merge](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) function:

```
Map<String, Object> finalMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

for (Map map : someObjectsList) {
    for (Object key : map.keySet()) {
        String value = ((String) map.get(key));
        finalMap.merge((String) key, value, (k, v) -> k + "," + v);
    }
}
```

which outputs:

> {2017-07-21=2017-07-21-07.33.28.429340,2017-07-21-07.33.28.429540,
>   2017-07-24=2017-07-24-01.23.33.591340,2017-07-24-01.23.33.492340}

---

The same can be achieved by the following one-liner:

```
someObjectsList.stream()
               .flatMap(i -> i.entrySet().stream())
               .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, 
                                        (k, v) -> k + "," + v));
```

Answer (score 1):

On your code, you are using different StringJoiner on each map. So, it's creating a new instance of it.

You can save your keys on a map. An example code:
(Edit: I did not remove your StringJoiner part.)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<Map<String, Object>> someObjectsList = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

        Map<String, Object> mapOne = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        mapOne.put("2017-07-21", "2017-07-21-07.33.28.429340");

        Map<String, Object> mapTwo = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        mapTwo.put("2017-07-24", "2017-07-24-01.23.33.591340");

        Map<String, Object> mapThree = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        mapThree.put("2017-07-24", "2017-07-24-01.23.33.492340");

        Map<String, Object> mapFour = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        mapFour.put("2017-07-21", "2017-07-21-07.33.28.429540");

        someObjectsList.add(mapOne);
        someObjectsList.add(mapTwo);
        someObjectsList.add(mapThree);
        someObjectsList.add(mapFour);

        Map<String, Object> outputMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        for (Map map : someObjectsList) {
            StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(",");
            for (Object key : map.keySet()) {
                String value = ((String) map.get(key));
                String date = value.substring(0, Math.min(value.length(), 10));
                //System.out.println(str);
                //System.out.println(value);

                if(key.equals(date)) {
                    sj.add(value);
                    System.out.println(sj.toString());
                    if(outputMap.containsKey(key)) {
                        String str = (String) map.get(key);
                        str = str + "," + value;
                        outputMap.put((String)key, str);
                    } else {
                        outputMap.put((String)key, value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for (String map : outputMap.keySet()) {
             System.out.println(map + " " + outputMap.get(map));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you're using `Object` over `String` and avoiding safety checks? That said, it's not "the first 10 characters", you want to see if `value` starts with `key` full-stop (all your keys are 10 characters). So in that case you can just do `if (value.startsWith(key)) { ... }`. Don't forget your newlines if the stringjoiner wasn't full. Lastly, you don't need a `List`, a `Map` can hold multiple keys at once. An alternative way of doing it:

```
//LinkedHashMap will preserve our insertion order
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put("2017-07-21", "2017-07-21-07.33.28.429340");
map.put("2017-07-24", "2017-07-24-01.23.33.591340");
//note duplicates are overwritten, but no value change here
map.put("2017-07-24", "2017-07-24-01.23.33.492340");
map.put("2017-07-21", "2017-07-21-07.33.28.429540");
//  You can also use Java 8 streams for the concatenation
//  but I left it simple
List<String> matches = map.entrySet()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue().startsWith(e.getKey())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
String concatenated = String.join("\n", matches);
```

If you wanted to generate that string without streams, it would look like this (again, not using `#entrySet` for simplicity, but it would be more efficient here):

```
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner("\n");
for (String key : map.keySet()) {
    String value = map.get(key);
    if (value.startsWith(key)) {
        joiner.add(value);
    }
}
//joiner#toString will give the expected result
```

Comment: Thanks! Plus one for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the *grouping* behavior of processing a `List`. You can use the advantage of [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream) since [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8). In any case, you need a new `Map` to store the values in order to print them. :

```
someObjectsList.stream()
        .flatMap(i -> i.entrySet().stream())               // flatmapping to entries
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getKey))     // grouping them using the key
```

In case you want to use for-loops. In this case it is harder since the more entries might appear in each List item:

```
final Map<String, List<Object>> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Map<String, Object> m: someObjectsList) {          // iterate List<Map>
    for (Entry<String, Object> entry: m.entrySet()) {   // iterate entries of each Map
        List<Object> list;
        final String key = entry.getKey();              // key of the entry
        final Object value = entry.getValue();          // value of the entry
        if (map.containsKey(key)) {                     // if the key exists
            list = map.get(key);                        // ... use it
        } else {
            list = new ArrayList<>();                   // ... or else create a new one
        }
        list.add(value);                                // add the new value
        map.put(key, list);                             // and add/update the entry
    }
}
```

Printing out of `Map<String, List<Object>> map` in both cased will produce the following output:

```
2017-07-21=[2017-07-21-07.33.28.429340, 2017-07-21-07.33.28.429540], 
2017-07-24=[2017-07-24-01.23.33.591340, 2017-07-24-01.23.33.492340]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The solution is quite interesting. Plus one for it.